# Error on sudo apt-get update, 404 not found (previous solutions do not work for me)

Tags: apt, 20.04

when entering: sudo apt-get update, I get the following error

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu focal InRelease
...
Ign:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                    
Ign:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease         
Err:12 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::25 80]
Hit:13 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:14 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::25 80]
Err:15 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::25 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have checked out other forums on this website but none of them provided me with solutions that resolve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated,

Zador

Comment: Please note I removed some lines of the message from the terminal and replaced it with "...". I did this because otherwise the post was viewed as spam.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is not EOL (*end-of-life*) thus hasn't had it's archives moved to *old-releases*  (that will only occur after the ESM has ended; likely May 2030 at a guess).  Why did you make that change now???

Comment: @nobody I believe this solved it. I have no idea what I did though (I am new to ubuntu)

after applying sudo apt-get update, I get fewer Hit:# outputs and fewer Get:# outputs and in the end the output is as follows:
`Fetched 3’721 B in 1s (4’260 B/s)         
Reading package lists... Done`

Does this look right to you? Can you perhaps briefly tell me what happened?

Comment: @guiverc I don't know what all this means... I'm sorry I'm new to Ubuntu. Have I done something at some point that I really shouldn't have? It sounds like I must have followed some instructions in a forum that was not meant for my version of Ubuntu. I hope this is not a big issue.

Comment: @karel could you please briefly look at my response to "nobody"? Do you believe I should still check out what you shared? I am now afraid to touch anything I don't have to.

Comment: Not it's not a big issue, the lines in your output show `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` where instead of `old-releases` it should say `archive` ... Someone on your box with `sudo` access changed the 'archive' to 'old-releases' which is required **after** a release has gone EOL (*end-of-life*).  If you change it back to `archive` it's done.

Comment: @guiverc after applying what "nobody" suggested my command works without any errors and I no longer see anythine with `old-releases`. Moreover I checked under `Software & updates` and then `Other software` and again I do not see `old-releases` anywhere. It sounds like my issue has been solved?

Comment: Yep... accept the duplicate @nobody suggested  (I've already marked I agree with uptick of it... my description was just how I'd achieve it (without specific names; I'd use `vi` (*1970s written editor*) at terminal, but it can be accomplished in many many ways (inc. GUI tools)

Answer (score 1):

Your sources list is wrong. Focal is not in Old-releases as pointed out by guiverc.

[How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)